# How to find all names that begin with “S” but only have 4 characters in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How to find all names that begin with `S` but only have 4 characters in SQL Server 2014.

I tried using the Where clauses below but they did not work.

```
Where Name Like 'S%%%' 
and 
Where Name Like 'S _ _ _' 
and
Where Name Like 'S***'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you put spaces between your pattern? You would have got it just by removing the spaces

```
Where Name Like 'S___'
```

Comment: Thank you. i overlooked that.

Answer (score 4):

Use the SQL `LEN` function to view the length of the field. [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp)

Try this:

```
Select * 
From MyTable
Where Name like 'S%' and LEN(Name) = 4
```

Comment: This works if one of the equal signs is dropped.Select * 
From MyTable
Where Name like 'S%' and LEN(Name) = 4. Thanks for posting

Comment: Ah sorry, too much Javascript and C# coding :)